# What happens in the final scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, reality

In the final scene of [Reality](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1846487/), is Luciano actually inside the Big Brother house? Or has he completely lost his grip on reality while watching television?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is left as being *ambiguous* as we can see with many of the film endings today. One may hint that the maniac laughter and his general behavior may hint towards a certain losing of the mind, and hence all of it not being real. But there is no such *evidence* to indicate that it may have happened so. May be it was for real, and he was always mad by then. Could be interpreted as anything with a good argument.